# Using db.collection with the strict flag not working in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

It's just a simple check that if the collection doesn't exist then create it and prepopulate with data. This works fine on my local box and depends on the "strict" flag being set on the db.collection call which will throw an error if the coll doesn't exist. It doesn't work on Heroku however, anyone know why?

```
mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
  if (!err)
  {
    console.log("Connected to Database")
    db.collection('collectionName', {strict:true}, function(er, collection) {
      if (!er)
      {
        console.log("Collection opened, ready for use!")
      } else {
        console.log("DATA DOES NOT EXIST, PREPOPULATING")
        populateDB();
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Error connecting to database: " + err)
  }
});
```

package.json

```
    {
    "name": "appname",
    "description": "Application",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.x",
        "mongodb": "1.3.x",
        "socket.io": "0.9.10"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.8.4",
        "npm": "1.1.49"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I updated Node to version 0.10.x in the package.json file and that seemed to fix it.